# Datetime format retrieved as VarChar (String) when getting as resultset in java

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, classcastexception, mysql-5.6

We have migrated from mysql 5.5 to 5.6. 
Because of that some operation fails with ClassCastException.
Since "datetime" field comes as String format when we are retriving using JDBC.
Problem exists with dattime timestamp. Is there any property need to be set in mysql.

I have tried setting sqlmode to empty from default valu

Comment: Could you please provide the full exception?

Comment: It's not direct error from DB. In my code when I am getting the value of Datetime field from db and typecasting to Date or TimeStamp it throws java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date. which was fine with mysql 5.5    TimeStamp time;                  
  time = (Timestamp)row[index5];  //row[index5] is datetime or timestamp field.